# proof of each row of self product of transition matrix sums to 1

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, markov-chains, markov, markov-models

I am unable to proof that the sum of each row of self product of a transition matrix is 1...

Let A be a transition probability matrix which means that each row of A sums to 1, and let P=A*A.

I want the prove that P is a also a valid transition matrix,i.e each row of P sums to 1.

Please Help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two transition matrices A (m x p) and B (p x n), we want to prove that C = AB (m x n) is a transition matrix.

We know that C<sub>ij</sub> = Σ<sub>k</sub> A<sub>ik</sub> B<sub>kj</sub>.

What is the sum of the ith row of C?

Σ<sub>j</sub> C<sub>ij</sub> 
= Σ<sub>j</sub> Σ<sub>k</sub> A<sub>ik</sub> B<sub>kj</sub> 
= Σ<sub>k</sub> Σ<sub>j</sub> A<sub>ik</sub> B<sub>kj</sub> 
= Σ<sub>k</sub> A<sub>ik</sub> (Σ<sub>j</sub> B<sub>kj</sub>) 
= Σ<sub>k</sub> A<sub>ik</sub> 
= 1

Therefore C is a transition matrix.